# PHP/MySQL Update Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form with several select and text boxes that gets dynamically generated from a database query.
The number of rows (The form lives in a html table) depends on how many records gets returned from the database.
For instance:

Row 1 - MUStatus(dropdown), IPlan(dropdown), ATT(text box) 
Row 2 - MUStatus(dropdown), IPlan(dropdown), ATT(text box) 
Row 3 - MUStatus(dropdown), IPlan(dropdown), ATT(text box) 
...
...
...
Row 10 - MUStatus(dropdown), IPlan(dropdown), ATT(text box)

Not all rows are going to be updated all the time. Maybe a user gets a 10-row form and updates only one.
My processing script needs to loop through all rows to figure out which one has changed in order to update. This causes
the update query to run 10 times even if the user only updates one row.
How can I get it to update only the number of rows that has been changed on the form?

Currently this is my processing script (not sanatized yet. Just in test mode)

```
for($i = 0; $i < $_POST['totalRecords']; $i++){
    if($_POST['muStatus'] != $providerMUStatusArray[$i] ||         
       $_POST['att1IncentivePlanDropDown'!= $providerATT1IncentivePlanArray[$i] ||
       $_POST['att1AttestationNumber'!=  $providerATT1NumberArray[$i]){
        UPDATE QUERY GOES HERE
    }//END IF
}//END FOR
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it: I would add a hidden field in each row called "Updated" with a start value of 0 then use JQuery or just JavaScript to set it to 1 every time a value in that row is changed.

Even better, I would use AJAX to update each row as soon as the user is done editing it.

Comment: Thanks Sunknight0. I swear I tried the jQuery path, but got stuck and had to go back to the conventional way due to a tight deadline.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a session and store the values you expect. Then when the form is submitted you just check to see if the submitted value equals the session saved value. If it does not equal it then process.